# Why is the order of the subgroup 3?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, dihedral-groups

I want to find the order of the subgroup $\langle ab\rangle$ of $D_3=\langle a,b\mid a^3=1,b^2=1,ba=a^2b\rangle$

According to my notes, the order of this subgroup is 3.  But why is it like that?

I thought that it would be 2,because :

$$(ab)^1=ab$$
$$(ab)^2=(ab)(ab)=a(ba)b=aa^2bb=a^3b^2=1$$

Isn't it like that?

***EDIT:*** The diagram of the subgroups of $D_3$ that is in my notes is:

[image]

But, is the right one maybe like that?

[image]

Comment: Yes. You got it right.

Comment: Are you sure it didn't say index rather than order?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese What is the index of the subgroup??

Comment: The index of $H$ in $G$ is the number of cosets $gH$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese And how can I find the number of the cosets $gH$ ?

Comment: In general, if $H$ is a subgroup of a finite group $G$, then the index of $H$ in $G$ is denoted by $[G : H]$ and is given by $[G:H] = \frac{|G|}{|H|}$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese At my post,I added the diagramm of the subgroups of $D_3$.Do,the red numbers $1,2,3,6$ represent the order or the index?

Comment: The red numbers are intended to be the order (because the trivial subgroup has a red $1$ and the whole group has a red $6$). There are two errors in the diagram: the one you found and the analogous one for $\langle a^2b\rangle$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I tried to make it by myself and added the diagramm at my first post..Could you tell me if it is right?

Comment: Yes, the second diagram looks correct.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Nice,thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 3):

As has been discussed in the comments, the subgroup $\langle ab\rangle < D_3$ has order two (as you correctly demonstrated) and has index three. Furthermore, your second diagram is correct; it is the subgroup lattice for $D_3$ where the red numbers indicate the order of each subgroup in the corresponding row.